# Which relative clause is not reduced?

Tags: relative-clauses

I have read in one page: If a subject relative clause does not include BE, you can't simply reduce it. So, a sentence like this "I know a woman who works there."  cannot be reduced. What would you say?

Comment: I would strongly advise you to drop the term "reduce". "I know a woman working there" is semantically similar to the relative clause in "I know a woman who works there", The _ing_ clause does modify "woman" but it is a gerund-participial clause, not a 'reduced' relative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A participle can often be used instead of a relative pronoun and full verb :

> I know a woman *who works there*.

( *"Who works there"* = Relative clause)

This relative clause can be reduced by using present participle :

> I know a woman *working there*.